# Describing a set

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it possible to describe a set $\left\lbrace(x,y,z)\mid x \sin z + y \cos z = e^z \right\rbrace$ on the neighborhood of $(2, 1, 0)$ as a graph of a function $f$, where $f(2,1) = 0$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look at $F(x,y,z) = x\sin z+y\cos z - e^z$ and compute $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(2,1,0)$.

Comment: As a sidenote, [this text](https://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnmvafolder/mva03.pdf) seems good.